# Debugging Angular Bindings

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-bindings

I am just starting with angular.js version 2 .
(Still using jQuery after all these years :-) )
There is still alot to learn.

One particular thing that bothers me: How do I debug binding problems in the DOM.
For example if I bind a click event and make a mistake:

If instead of:

```
<... (click)="onClick()" ...>
```

I write:

```
<... (click)="ThisFunctionCallIsMissspelledAndIsMissingParantheses" ...>
```

I find that the browser is completely happy to swallow up this syntax error and just ignore the click without printing out any error.

Also, assuming I am not the one that made this mistake (many times I need to debug other peoples' code) I cannot find this binding in the DOM. When I "Inspect Element" in the browser, all that's left in the tag are: "ngcontent_c0" hashes. (The original binding is gone).

So my questions are:

1. Can I get the browser to spit out an error such as: **ThisFunctionCallIsMissspelledAndIsMissingParantheses is undefined**
2. If I am debugging someone else's code, is there some way I can use the browser to get a hint of what is wrong? Can I somehow see in the DOM that ThisFunctionCallIsMissspelledAndIsMissingParantheses  is bound to said button? I am working with "ng serve" in debug mode: So I can see the .ts files. However the angular HTML bindings seem to be hashed.

Comment: Angular certainly throws an error if you're trying to call a function that does not exist. [See stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bfs3qz?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: In my example, you will notice that the although the dev intended to call the function, she both misspelled the function and forgot the parenthesis. As such, the function is not being called (no parenthesis), but the undefined symbol does not provide an error. Also, it's not in the page's DOM. So the dev tasked with debugging is faced with a button which does nothing, but no obvious way to debug it. (no DOM inspection and no Error messages).

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't saw that. I think the only solution is to write tests... So you'll see something went wrong for that specific button